# How to use WTSRegisterSessionNotification?

Tags: c++, windows, notifications

I would like to use `WTSRegisterSessionNotification`. According to MSDN: `Session change notifications are sent in the form of a WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE message.`

So my question is, how can I use `WTSRegisterSessionNotification` and do something at `WTS_SESSION_LOGON` event?

Is it possible to use these functions in a service somehow?
If yes, could someone help me, with a simple example. I couldn't find anywhere.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: From your link: "To receive session change notifications from a service, use the HandlerEx function."

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Thank you, but in the meantime i already got it working :)